# Glade: how to make a Button close the Window?

Tags: gtk, glade, pygobject

I would like to know if is possible to make a `Gtk.Button` close it own `Gtk.Dialog` directly form Glade (without writing any code in C/Python/whatever).

[image]

If I enable the window decoration I have a working round 'x' icon that does exactly that, but I would like to use my own button to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do this. Glade only lets you name the signal handler function that will run when that signal is emitted.

The X on the window decoration is implemented by your OS, so Glade has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same suspect, I just wanted to ask in case I was missing something. Thanks for the answer.